# Ruby on Rails , habtm collect method not collecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to backup data to a yaml store on deletion like so:

```
DeleteProject.create!(:data => {
  :project => project.attributes, 
  :domains => project.domains.collect(&:attributes), 
  :databases => project.databases.collect(&:attributes)
}.to_yaml)
```

However although the project and domain data is stored fine, databases is always coming back blank. The relationship is done via

- **has_and_belongs_to_many :databases**
- **has_and_belongs_to_many :projects**

I am at a dead end with this one as I do not know why it simply would not be passing in the current data from project.databases. Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any default_scope which filter the data???

Comment: There is nothing filtering the data, all of the information is there as it is being used in the show project action with the exact same request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed this by doing the following:

- has_many :database_connections
- has_many :databases, :through =>
  :database_connections

Updated models to use has_many and then updated the connecting table no longer database_projects but database_connections.

```
class DatabaseConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :projects, :class_name => "Project",
                        :foreign_key => "project_id"
  belongs_to :databases, :class_name => "Database",
                         :foreign_key => "database_id"
end
```